# Is Knights of the Fallen empire and Lvl 65 only available to subscribers?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is Knights of the Fallen empire and Lvl 65 only available to subscribers? can you just pay for it directly like you could Hutt Cartel and Shadow of Revan? I don't see it for purchase in the store/website. I just hit level 60 with one of my characters, but I don't think I'm leveling anymore...

Comment: http://www.swtor.com/support/helpcenter/7418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not.  The only way to play Knights of the Fallen Empire is by subscribing.  The good part about subscribing, though, is that you get every single expansion with it now.  So for a $15 payment, you get the Rise of the Hutt Cartel, Shadow of Revan, and the newest, Knights of the Fallen Empire.  Plus the month's bonus of being a subscriber.

Comment: but I have those all already... so nice for new subscribers... but a bit of a screw you to me. I wasn't expecting it for free... but... maybe for a 1 month it'll do. I only play for like 1-3 weeks every 6 months though... so I certainly would never do a reoccuring. Anyways thanks for the answer that I can't ask them.

Comment: Think I'll just play other characters until I hit level 60, then I'll look at subscribing for a month.

Comment: One thing that might be worth noting is that all the content for Fallen Empire isn't out yet.  So you might want to hold off on subscribing until it's fully released, to get all the content for the cost of a month.

Comment: Note that Knights of the Fallen Empire is split into chapters.  If you're a subscriber and unsubscribe, only the chapters that were out when you were a subscriber will be available to play.